# quill text editor for textarea is not working correctly with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, quill

I want to use [quilljs-textarea](https://www.github.com/tangien/quilljs-textarea) in my project hosted [here](https://logical-error.000webhostapp.com/), but it gives me weird output as shown:

[image: snapshot of out put]

please any body help me.

Comment: Please provide some code. The link you have provided is likely to die in the future, while this question will live on and will no longer make sense to anyone reading it. Also, questions should provide an MVP - whoever's answering should not be bothered with tons of irrelevant details. It is also desirable that the question/answers are important/useful not only to you, but also to other people on SO.

Comment: @Avius I was aware of that, but where can I store those _static resources_ (i.e css, js e.t.c..)?

Comment: First I suggest you take a close look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Most of the code in your website is irrelevant, so there is no need to include complete static resources. We only need to see how you initialise Quill and the bits of HTML and CSS that are specifically related to it - use code blocks for that. _Additionally_ you may include a Plunker/etc. demo which demonstrates the core of the problem. Yes, it's still a link, but it's the next best thing in this case. This is the homework needed to help people answer your question.